# Is fingering wife's vagina legal in Islam?

Tags: wife, husband

Is it allowed in Islam to enter fingers in wife's vagina?

Comment: @Mustaghees, Can a husband enter his fingers in his wife's vagina for fulfilling sexual needs?
Is it legal in Islam?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, it is legal.**

It is permissible for a Muslim man to enter his fingers in his wife's vagina. And it's also permissible for the wife to touch his penis. All kinds of sexual acts except anal sex and sex during wife's menses is permissible in Islam.
 Allah almighty, may He be glorified and exalted, says in the Qur'an (interpretation of the meaning):

> [2:223] Your wives are as a tilth unto you; **so approach your tilth when or how
>   ye will;** but do some good act for your souls beforehand; and fear
>   Allah. And know that ye are to meet Him (in the Hereafter), and give
>   (these) good tidings to those who believe.

Answer (score 0):

Since it has been mentioned above about oral sex , I have not found anything in any Islamic book that says oral sex is Haram , it has been mentioned by some scholars that is permissable but it's Makroh and some of the say it's Haram but nowhere in Quran it's been mentioned .
ALLAH swt knows best

Answer (score -2):

Brothers anal sex oral sex and sex during menses period is strictly prohibited in islam and Quran from Allah Subhaanahu 2:223] Your wives are as a tilth unto you; so approach your tilth when or how ye will; but do some good act for your souls beforehand; and fear Allah. And know that ye are to meet Him (in the Hereafter), and give (these) good tidings to those who believe. is given for because Muslims do can sex in only according to Islamic laws not for and from haram pleasure we are human and Alhamdulillah Muslims not animals